# Remove NA inside column from Datafarme

Tags: r, shinydashboard, dt

I have a DT::datatable as following:

[image: Datatable]
I converted data table to data.frame,

```
output$viewresponses<-DT::renderDataTable({
    view <- read.csv("www/kpi.csv", header=TRUE)

    viewDF<-as.data.frame(view)
    viewDF<-subset(viewDF,select=-c(X,used_shiny))
    print(viewDF %>%  spread(name,r_num_years))

    DT::datatable(res %>%  spread(name,r_num_years),extensions = 'Responsive')

  }
```

)
data.frame is as following:

```
  cost customer-satisfaction safety time
1    NA          57             NA   NA
2    NA          72             NA   NA
3    NA          73             NA   NA
4    NA          NA             NA   NA
5    NA          NA             NA   24
6    NA          NA             NA   40
7    NA          NA             NA   22
8    40          NA             NA   NA
9    38          NA             NA   NA
10   36          NA             NA   NA
11   NA          NA             32   NA
12   NA          NA             30   NA
13   NA          NA             58   NA
```

I want to remove all NA and get the following table

```
   cost customer-satisfaction safety  time
    40         57               32     24
    38         72               30     40
    36         73               58     22
```

and the result is :
[image: Remove all NA from each column in a DT::datatable]

I have modified the question as follows:
There is a data frame,

```
 df<-`data.frame(cost=c(NA,NA,NA,1),time=c(NA,NA,3,NA),Quality=c(NA,4,NA,NA),
    customersatisfaction=c(2,NA,NA,NA)`)
 cost time Quality customersatisfaction
1   NA   NA      NA                    2
2   NA   NA       4                   NA
3   NA    3      NA                   NA
4    1   NA      NA                   NA
```

I want to remove all NA from above data table and get the below result:

```
  cost time Quality customersatisfaction
1    1    3       4                    2
```

Comment: What would be the usefulness of such data.frame? And why the row with `satisfaction` equal `81` would disappear?

Comment: You need to define some relations which exist in the table, if you want to get some actual R code for this.

Comment: Strangely, there is no `81` row anymore in the question.

Comment: I think that my question is very clear, I just want to remove all NA from dataTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop through the columns, remove the NA elements, then select the minimum number of observations after comparing all the elements in the `list`.

```
 lst <- lapply(df1, function(x) x[complete.cases(x)])
 res <- data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`,min(lengths(lst))))
 res
 #  cost customer.satisfaction safety time
 #1   40                    57     32   24
 #2   38                    72     30   40
 #3   36                    73     58   22
```

Comment: thanks why they give me negative ?

Comment: @user Updated the post.  I guess now it is the same as the expected you showed.

Comment: @akrun Not only do you encourage the flood of low quality, zero effort questions on SO by answering them, you also upvote them... ("I upvoted for you now"). Congratulations with your reps!

Comment: thanks, but really I searched and could not find the right answer. I am sure that this question will be useful.

Comment: @user I would have used `na.omit` but it was only based on your previous example, I tried this route.

Comment: I have updated my question please look at it again, because I cannot get the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much I found my problem, I have to remove ''spread'' from "DT::datatable(res %>%  spread(name,r_num_years),extensions = 'Responsive') ''

Comment: It has to be changed as follows:
        'res <- data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`,min(lengths(lst))))
        DT::datatable(res,extensions = 'Responsive')'

Answer (score 2):

If the number of `NA`s is identical for all columns, you can use `na.omit`.

```
data.frame(lapply(dat, na.omit))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

The result:

```
  cost customer.satisfaction safety time
1   40                    57     32   24
2   38                    72     30   40
3   36                    73     58   22
```

Comment: but what if the number of NA is nor similar in each column?

Comment: @user - You should be explaining to us what would happen in that situation, not the other way around. It should be part of your post.